# 'Failed to configure a DataSource: 'url' attribute is not specified and no embedded datasource could be configured.' error in springboot application

Tags: java, postgresql, spring-boot, jdbc, apache-camel

I created a springboot application that uses Spring Boot and Apache Camel JDBC Component for inserting a record in postgreSQL. For this purpose I am using the following dependencies:

```
    <dependency>
                <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
                <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
                <scope>runtime</scope>
            </dependency>
        <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-jdbc</artifactId>
            </dependency>
        <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-dbcp2</artifactId>
        <version>2.9.0</version>
    </dependency>
        <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
        <artifactId>camel-jdbc</artifactId>
        <version>${camel.version}</version>
        <!-- use the same version as your Camel core version -->
    </dependency>
```

As for the database configuration, I created the following java class with an application.properties file:

Database Configuration java class:

```
    import java.io.FileInputStream;
    import java.io.IOException;
    import java.util.Properties;
    import org.apache.camel.support.SimpleRegistry;
    import org.apache.commons.dbcp2.BasicDataSource;
    
    
    public class DatabaseConfiguration {
        public static SimpleRegistry createDatabaseConfiguration() throws IOException {
            Properties properties = new Properties();
            properties.load(new FileInputStream("src/main/resources/application.properties"));
            BasicDataSource basic = new BasicDataSource();
            basic.setDriverClassName(properties.getProperty("PostgresDBClassname"));
            basic.setUsername(properties.getProperty("PostgresDBUsername"));
            basic.setPassword(properties.getProperty("PostgresDBPassword"));
            basic.setUrl(properties.getProperty("PostgresDBUrl"));
            SimpleRegistry registry = new SimpleRegistry();
            registry.bind("myDataSource", basic);
            return registry;
        }
    }
```

application.properties file:

```
PostgresDBUsername = username
PostgresDBPassword = password
PostgresDBClassname = org.postgresql.Driver
PostgresDBUrl = jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/postgres
```

I wrote the router in the following way, noting that I tried to replace dataSource with myDataSource:

```
   @Component
public class InsertRestService extends RouteBuilder {

  

    @Override
    public void configure() throws Exception {
        

        rest("/").produces("text/plain")
            .get("insert")
            .to("direct:hello");

        from("direct:hello")
            .transform().simple("INSERT INTO person (name, country) VALUES (DANY, LB)")
            .to("jdbc:dataSource") //spring boot starter jdbc creates the bean in the registry
            .transform().simple("Data inserted in Postgres successfully");
    }
}
```

I got the following error:

```
Failed to configure a DataSource: 'url' attribute is not specified and no embedded datasource could be configured.

Reason: Failed to determine a suitable driver class
```

I provided the URL in the application.properties file PostgresDBUrl

Also note that I downloaded the jdbc driver jar file and added it to the module path, after a right click on the package, build path, configure build path
[image]
So what can I do to solve this issue?
Thank you!!

Comment: Get rid of your configuration: This is what Boot does for you. Simply set `spring.datasource.url` and either include the username/password with `:`/`@` or also set the username and password properties.

Answer (score 1):

I removed the configuration file (DatabaseConfiguration) and replaced the content of the application.properties file with:

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/test
spring.datasource.username=username
spring.datasource.password=password
spring.datasource.platform=postgres
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=none
```

and it worked!

Answer (score 1):

Check your pom.xml file and switch its packaging into **war**. It worked for me.

```
<packaging>war</packaging>
```

Comment: Got this error after adding and deleting a module from a project, never noticed it changed the <packaging> tag to pom. Switched it back to jar and working fine.

Comment: Why does it not work with pom packaging?